Telynx API:Dial - the from_display_name property is not being respected
When using the NodeJs API like so, the from_display_name property is not having any effect on the receiving device. What makes this even stranger is that is was working a few weeks ago.  I'm not sure if I changed something and broke this but the customer service reps have not been able to help me track down why the values I'm setting in the from_display_name field is not showing on the receiving mobile device.
It was working at one point - so I know this does work.
      const newCall = await telnyx.calls.create({
        connection_id: customer.telnyx_connection_id,
        to: customer.phone_number,
        from: customer.telnyx_phone_number,
        from_display_name: `Incoming from ${event.data.payload.from}`,
        answering_machine_detection: 'premium'
      });

Setting the from_display_name property would show up on the receiving device as the from caller on the screen.  Suddenly this just stopped working.  Currently I'm trying to use the CNAM Listing as advised with a random value.  I was told that the value doesn't matter BUT it being toggled on will register the number with CNAM and allow the value I dynamically set to show up on the device.  I was told it would take up to 48 hours to work so I'm currently in the waiting window for this test and will follow up in another 24 hours with the results of this update.
